Ошибки при запуске Теста на Espresso
Моя проблема заключается в том, что тесты с помощью Espresso постоянно падают. В начале причина была понятна, это асинхронная операция но добавив idling resource ничего не изменилось.
Ниже представляю код теста
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class AppActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<AppActivity> mActivityScenarioRule =
            new ActivityScenarioRule<>(AppActivity.class);

    @Before // Выполняется перед тестами
    public void registerIdlingResources() { //Подключаемся к “счетчику”
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(EspressoIdlingResources.idlingResource);
    }
    @After // Выполняется после тестов
    public void unregisterIdlingResources() { //Отключаемся от “счетчика”
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(EspressoIdlingResources.idlingResource);
    }

    @Test
    public void appActivityTest() {
        ViewInteraction textInputEditText = onView(
                allOf(childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        allOf(withId(R.id.login_text_input_layout),
                                                childAtPosition(
                                                        childAtPosition(
                                                                withClassName(is("android.widget.RelativeLayout")),
                                                                1),
                                                        0)),
                                        0),
                                0),
                        isDisplayed()));
        textInputEditText.perform(replaceText("login2"), closeSoftKeyboard());

        ViewInteraction textInputEditText2 = onView(
                allOf(childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        allOf(withId(R.id.password_text_input_layout),
                                                childAtPosition(
                                                        childAtPosition(
                                                                withClassName(is("android.widget.RelativeLayout")),
                                                                1),
                                                        1)),
                                        0),
                                0),
                        isDisplayed()));
        textInputEditText2.perform(replaceText("password2"), closeSoftKeyboard());

        ViewInteraction materialButton = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.enter_button), withText("Sign in"), withContentDescription("Save"),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        childAtPosition(
                                                childAtPosition(
                                                        withId(R.id.nav_host_fragment),
                                                        0),
                                                2),
                                        1),
                                2),
                        isDisplayed()));
        materialButton.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction textView = onView(
                allOf(withText("News"),
                        withParent(withParent(allOf(withId(R.id.container_list_news_include_on_fragment_main),
                                withParent(withParent(IsInstanceOf.<View>instanceOf(android.widget.ScrollView.class)))))),
                        isDisplayed()));
        textView.check(matches(withText("News")));
    }

    private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
}

А тут файл idlingResource
public class EspressoIdlingResources {
    private static final String RESOURCE = "GLOBAL";//Tag
    public static CountingIdlingResource idlingResource = new CountingIdlingResource(RESOURCE);
    public static void increment() {
        idlingResource.increment();
    }
    public static void decrement() {
        if(!idlingResource.isIdleNow()) {
            idlingResource.decrement();
        }
    }
}


А здесь ошибка
failed: appActivityTest(ru.iteco.fmhandroid.ui.AppActivityTest)
----- begin exception -----
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (Child at position 0 in parent Child at position 0 in parent (view.getId() is <2131231037/ru.iteco.fmhandroid:id/login_text_input_layout> and Child at position 0 in parent Child at position 1 in parent view.getClass().getName() matches: is "android.widget.RelativeLayout") and (view has effective visibility <VISIBLE> and view.getGlobalVisibleRect() to return non-empty rectangle))

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1344, height=2992, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302fe
  fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
  pfl=NO_MOVE_ANIMATION FORCE_DRAW_STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND FIT_INSETS_CONTROLLED
  bhv=DEFAULT
  fitSides=}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2} 
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1344, height=2848, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2} 
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16908720, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1344, height=2848, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} 
|
+--->FitWindowsLinearLayout{id=2131230784, res-name=action_bar_root, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1344, height=2848, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---->ViewStubCompat{id=2131230801, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1344, height=2848, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} 
|
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewHierarchyExceptionHandler.handleSafely(ViewHierarchyExceptionHandler.java:38)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$TypedFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:158)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:120)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:385)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:212)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:140)
    at ru.iteco.fmhandroid.ui.AppActivityTest.appActivityTest(AppActivityTest.java:71)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:162)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:68)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:463)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)


Прошу помогите решить проблему и направить на путь истинный, я только учусь этому но даже преподаватель отказывается что то объяснять.....
В самом начале и гугл и чат GPT и пытался что то понять в документации.
